# Counterpart of "John Doe, Joe Public"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, nombres-propios

In English these names are used as a substitute for the average guy. Or as a specimen when filling out a passport form.

What names/expressions are used in Spanish for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's depends on the use and, as far as I know, there is no official denomination.

On graves: *Desconocido/a + number* or *Indocumentado/a + number*

Official forms/documents: They usually use a common name + common    surnames something like *María García García* or *José Pérez García* or    even *Nombre: Nombre Apellidos: Apellido Apellido*

Surnames for un-recognized children (in Spain and out of use):    *Expósito*

While talking (informal): *Fulano*, *Zutano*, *tío*, as in *El fulano/tío ese de ahí*, *El otro día Fulano y Zutano...* (used if you want to talk about the events without saying who did or said what).

And, as said in comments, *Mengano* and the diminutive forms *fulanito*, *menganito*, *zutanito*.

Comment: And don't forger also about *Mengano*. Even the diminutive forms are quite common also: *Fulanito*, *Menganito*

Comment: Yo me acordaba de tío, y quizás he oído de "Fulano" antes, pero no estoy seguro de eso...

Comment: No es simplemente Juan sin nombre ? Al menos ese es el termino que se le da a los difuntos de los cuales se le desconoce el nombre o apellido real. Es un termino legalmente utilizado debido a que al difunto se le debe de llamar de una u otra manera mientras se indaga e investiga la identidad real.

Answer (score 4):

A formal equivalent of *John Doe* (e.g. legal matters) in Spanish is **N.N.**, derived from the Latin [nomen nescio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen_nescio). *Fulano*, *Perano*, *Zutano*, *Mengano*, etc are used informally.

Comment: Also an informal way of calling it the police sometimes (at least in Argentina) uses **Natalia Natalia** to refer to N.N. (no mater if male or female)