# What is Spanish for "John Doe" in Puerto Rico?

Tags: nombres-propios, puerto-rico

What is Puerto Rican Spanish for "John Doe" or "Jane Doe"? Is it still Fulano de Tal?

Comment: similar question to:http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/692/counterpart-of-john-doe-joe-public

Comment: Cuba: Fulano de Tal o Mascual, Mengano, Esperansejo y hasta Periquito Perez.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_nombre#Otros_nombres_utilizados_alrededor_del_mundo), it can be "Fulano de Tal", "Juan Pérez" or "Juan del Pueblo".

Comment: I'm used to say and hear "Juan Pueblo" but not "Juan [DEL] Pueblo".

Answer (score 2):

Also used are "Mengano", "Zutano", "Perengano" and "Perico de los Palotes".

Comment: Are these specifically used in Puerto Rico, or is your answer being general (or local to Spain)?

Comment: I'm sorry, these are used in Spain.

Comment: These are used in Argentina, too (except here it's Juan de los Palotes). I'm quite sure these are common in other Spanish speaking countries, though I'm not sure if that's the case in Puerto Rico.

Comment: They are used in Mexico as well.

Comment: In Guatemala I heard "Mengano", "Sutano" and "Perensejo", but not "Perengano". "Perico de los Palotes" is also understood, along with "Juan Pueblo" and "Juan Pérez" which IMHO is more like "John Doe" than the first ones. Unfortunately we don't have a "Jane Doe" equivalent, but I tend to say "María Gómez" when I need a female one.

Answer (score 2):

"Fulano or Fulana De Tal" is the legally accepted name for official documents.