# Términos para aludir a alguien cuyo nombre se desconoce

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, solicitud-de-término

En español parece haber una cantidad considerable de términos con los que aludir a personas cuyo nombre se desconoce. Algunos ya han salido en otras preguntas ([1](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/692/12637), [2](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3118/12637)), como:

- [fulano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IZm0LQU) (proveniente del árabe).
- [mengano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Othxah5) (proveniente tal vez del árabe).
- [zutano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cZGeuK3) (de *[citano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9MLEXg6)*, y éste del latín).
- [perengano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SZbN0e5) (posiblemente cruce de Pérez y mengano).

Así que me preguntaba: ¿existen aun más términos similares recogidos en el diccionario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buscando mediante el DIRAE me he encontrado con los siguientes términos (gracias a [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo), [AlexBcn](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1701/alexbcn) y [Rafael](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12621/rafael) por los añadidos):

> **[chorbo, ba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8ypN4yI)**
>
> Tb. [chorvo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=90MMeJQ).
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. Esp. Persona cuyo nombre y condición se ignoran o no se quieren decir.
> 2. m. coloq. Sujeto despreciable y de poco valer, cuyo nombre se ignora o se quiere omitir.
>
> **[esperancejo, ja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GYc56eY)**
>
> 1. m. y f. coloq. Cuba. fulano (‖ para aludir a alguien cuyo nombre se ignora o no se quiere expresar).
>
> **[individuo, dua](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LQCSlDx)**
>
> Del lat. *individuus* 'indivisible'.
>
> 3. m. y f. coloq. Persona cuyo nombre y condición se ignoran o no se quieren decir.
>
> **[NN](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QXiM8Ka)**
>
> De las iniciales del lat. *nomen nescio* 'desconozco el nombre'.
>
> 1. m. y f. Bol., Chile y Perú. Persona desconocida de la que no se tiene ningún dato.
>
> **[nota](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QdrVoo1)**
>
> Del lat. *nota*.
>
> 20. m. coloq. individuo (‖ hombre cuyo nombre se ignora).
>
> **[persona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SjUIL8Z)**
>
> Del lat. *persōna* 'máscara de actor', 'personaje teatral', 'personalidad', 'persona', este del etrusco *φersu*, y este del gr. *πρόσωπον prósōpon*.
>
> 2. f. Hombre o mujer cuyo nombre se ignora o se omite.
>
> **[quídam](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpMRRiS)**
>
> Del lat. *quidam* 'uno, alguno'.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Sujeto a quien se designa indeterminadamente.
>
> **[robiñano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WXstRv8)**
>
> 1. m. p. us. Nombre que se da a una persona cuyo nombre se ignora.
>
> **[sujeto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YgC4A98)**
>
> Del lat. *subiectus*, part. pas. de *subiicĕre* 'poner debajo', 'someter'.
>
> 3. m. Persona cuyo nombre se ignora o no se quiere decir.
>
> **[tío, a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZoWtFfy)**
>
> Del lat. tardío *thius*, y este del gr. *θεῖος theîos*.
>
> 7. m. y f. coloq. Persona cuyo nombre y condición se ignoran o no se quieren decir.
>
> **[tipo, pa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZpMjpMC)**
>
> Del lat. *typus*, y este del gr. *τύπος týpos*.
>
> 15. m. y f. coloq. persona (‖ individuo). U. t. en sent. despect., generalmente para referirse a una persona cuyo nombre se ignora.

Comment: También puedes agregar [tipo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZpMjpMC).

Comment: No sé si venga al caso, pero las distintas comunidades lingüísticas tienen palabras para referirse a otras personas de modo vago, amplio, coloquial y a veces despectivo. Por ejemplo los chilenos usamos para eso los términos _gallo_ y _compadre_. A veces también _loco_ y _mino_. Y no sé exactamente de qué país son, pero todos hemos escuchado _mae, man y güey_ más o menos con el mismo significado que dan los europeos a _tío_. Y en tono un poco más vulgar, _güevón, cabrón y carajo_.

Comment: @Rodrigo por supuesto que viene al caso. Yo he buscado términos en el DRAE, pero siempre habrá otros términos coloquiales no recogidos de uso regional. Te animo a que escribas tu propia respuesta con los términos que mencionas. Si es posible, pon alguna referencia de uso a algún texto de ejemplo que acredite su uso, o si no algún ejemplo.

Comment: Añado: esperancejo, ja *m. y f. coloq. Cuba. fulano (‖ para aludir a alguien cuyo nombre se ignora o no se quiere expresar).*

Comment: También se puede agregar la [latina](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/925/is-there-a-john-or-jane-doe-in-latin/927#927) y técnica sigla [N.N.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QXiM8Ka), que a juzgar por el DRAE ha caído en desuso en la mayoría del mundo hispanohablante, pero apostaría que sigue teniendo valor jurídico.

Answer (score 2):

Los invito a agregar aquí libremente los **regionalismos** con que aludimos a otras personas.

### Chile

- Güevón
- Compadre/comadre (a veces significa "amigo", pero generalmente significa "una persona").
- Gallo (El femenino es *galla*. P.ej. *Vino una galla a vender ropa.*)
- Loco
- Mina (también se usa el masculino *mino* pero es menos frecuente).

Comment: Tengo entendido que _mina_ se utiliza también en Argentina.