# Sustantivos para designar a un lugar cuyo nombre se desconoce

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

En la pregunta [Términos para aludir a alguien cuyo nombre se desconoce](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17999/12637) se hizo un repaso de aquellas formas de las que dispone el lenguaje para designar a las personas cuyo nombre se ignora o se quiere omitir. Sin embargo, ¿existe algún término similar para los lugares? ¿Qué término se usa para aquellos lugares de cuyo nombre no quieres acordarte? ¿Cuál es la versión de *fulano* para lugares?

Lo más parecido que se me ocurre (aunque no es lo que busco, ojo) es cuando quieres decir que algo está muy lejos, que se usan expresiones como *[la Conchinchina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochinchina#La_expresi.C3.B3n_popular)*, que no aparece en el DLE, aunque se encuentran textos en el CREA:

> *Bueno, lo que es yo, yo estaba ya en que eso del amor es una engañifa. Después ya no sé, no lo sé... Pero, antes de lo de mi Julio y el Lucas, yo convencida: el amor, la engañifa más grande que hay en el mundo. Aquí y en la Conchinchina.*
>
> Fernando Quiñones, "Las mil noches de Hortensia Romero", 1979 (España).

Comment: ¿"designar **a**"?

Comment: Extraido de un artículo de prensa (negritas mías): "Un escritor de Castilla, que se llamaba Miguel de Cervantes, aludía con frecuencia a las diferentes denominaciones vernáculas del bacalao; en cada región española hay un nombre especial para **designar a** ese delicioso pez noruego e islandés."

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - *designar a un pez* me parece bien, *designar a un lugar* no.

Comment: @aparente001 interesante. Había dado por sentado que la construcción era correcta, pero veo que hay cierta controversia. Podríamos plantearlo como pregunta, ¿os animáis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Español no hay un nombre genérico para un lugar cualquiera. Al decir "fulano" o "mengano" queremos decir tanto "un señor cualquiera" como "un señor del que no sabemos el nombre" (que sería "un desconocido").

Esto no se aplica a países. Lo más parecido sería usar "donde sea" y "no se dónde".

> Eso es como si llegase fulanito y dijese que quiere ir hasta no se dónde con todos los gastos pagados. Evidentemente no se puede
>
> Este ha estado de vacaciones donde sea y va a venir como siempre con las fotitos...

Evidentemente esto es un equivalente "geográfico" de "quien sea" y "no se quién" para personas, pero mientras que para personas tenemos tanto el "fulano", "mengano" etc. para países no hay nombre genérico.

Comment: "Nosedonde" suena bien, aunque no figure en el DRAE. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No creo que "Conchinchina" se refiera a un lugar desconocido sino a un lugar lejano. "aquí y en la Conchinchina" significaría "aquí y en cualquier parte del mundo".

Esos circunstanciales de lugar, creo, se adaptan a la toponimia de cada lugar. En Argentina decimos, por ejemplo, "de acá a La Quiaca" o "hasta en La Quiaca" (una zona montañosa, famosa por sus quebradas, en el extremo norte del país) para significar, respectivamente, una gran extensión o un lugar muy distante.

También se utilizan expresiones bastante groseras para significar distancias (físicas o virtuales) extremas. Una de ellas hace alusión a las partes pudendas de la lora (sí, la hembra del loro), en expresiones como: "Se fue hasta la c.... de la lora". También existe la forma eufemística de esta expresión: "Vive en Pluma Verde", en alusión al plumaje que cubre las partes mencionadas . Otra expresión, también vulgar, es "en la loma del o..."

Debo confesar que nunca creí que iba a escribir esto en mi vida y espero que esta participación no opaque el escaso prestigio que pude haber obtenido hasta aquí, si es que obtuve alguno.

Comment: Las expresiones coloquiales, vulgares (y hasta malsonantes) son una parte del lenguaje como cualquier otra, y no debe restar prestigio el tratar acerca de ellas. Es más, no deberíamos ni siquiera omitirlas o censurarlas. Si [la RAE no lo hace](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A81xUaG#4DsxGYt) cuando las añade al diccionario, y [la ASALE tampoco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=orto), ¿por qué deberíamos nosotros?

Comment: He modificado la pregunta para aclarar que lo que busco es la versión de _fulano_ para lugares: una palabra para un lugar desconocido, sin importar si está lejos o cerca. No tiene que dar la sensación de "lugar alejado o inaccesible" o que implique "aquí y en todas partes". Mi ejemplo de la Conchinchina fue desafortunado, lo siento, aunque tus ejemplos me han gustado.

Comment: En portugués está *algures*, que significa "en algún lugar" (el equivalente del inglés *somewhere*). ¿Habrá algún cognado en uso en español?

Comment: @pablodf76 nunca sabía que el portugués tenían esa palabra. El asturiano también tiene una parecida, *ayuri ~ ayures* con el mismo significado de *(en/a) algún lugar o alguna parte*. Una lástima que el castellano no la tenga.

Answer (score 3):

Usamos expresiones tipo "Aquí y en la **Conchinchina**" o "Aquí y en la China." (o la *china chapuchina*, *Pernambuco* o *Timbuktu*) con el significado de "eso es así en todos lados; aquí y en un sitio muy lejano". El que sea un sito lejano le da cierta validez de ser "universalmente cierta" a la afirmación, pues como decir "a lo largo del globo" o "por todo el mundo".

> Todos querríamos trabajar poco y cobrar mucho. Eso es así aquí y en la Conchinchina.

Para designar otros lugares "genéricos" lejanos usamos expresiones como

> Eso está en el **quinto pino**.
>
> Eso está **donde Cristo perdió el mechero**.
>
> Eso está **a tomar viento**.

Comment: Buenas opciones, pero todas dan la idea de un lugar remoto o inaccesible, mientras que yo buscaba sencillamente una palabra para un lugar desconocido, sin importar si está lejos o cerca. Como decir "fulano" pero para lugares. Tal vez no lo aclaré lo suficiente en la pregunta, y el ejemplo que puse fue desafortunado.

Comment: A propósito del quinto pino, he oído en alguna película "en el quinto infierno".