# ¿Se puede llamar a un niño o niña "Jaimito (a)"?

Tags: adjetivos, nombres-propios

Jaimito es un niño pequeño y bastante travieso, que continuamente está haciendo preguntas pícaras y jugándole bromas a la gente. ¿Se le puede llamar a cualquier niño con dicha descripción "Jaimito"?

Comment: Siempre se puede.  Creo que estás preguntando si te van a entender (los adultos, principalmente, me imagino).

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. ¿Estas preguntando si existe el adjetivo "Jaimito"? ej. *Ese niño es un Jaimito*.

Comment: te refieres como apodo o como nombre propio ?

Comment: Si es como descriptivo, con minúscula inicial; si es apodo, con mayúscula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está aceptado, aunque solo para niños varones.

> [**jaimito**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MIqClgl%7CMIut79R)
>
> De *Jaimito*, personaje de chistes.
>
> **1**. [m.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31116/12991) Niño caracterizado por un descaro, una malicia y una suficiencia impropios de sus años.

Tan solo hay que tener cuidado de escribirlo [con minúscula inicial](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp#63a), puesto que es un nombre común que puede pluralizarse, por ejemplo: "Dedicado a todos los jaimitos del mundo".

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!

Comment: No hay de qué, para eso estamos. Por favor, recuerde pulsar la marca verde en la respuesta que le resulte más útil. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Del DRAE

> [jaimito](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MIqClgl%7CMIut79R)
>
> *De Jaimito, personaje de chistes.*
>
> 1. m. Niño caracterizado por un descaro, una malicia y una suficiencia impropios de sus años.

Puedes hacerlo por supuesto, y además es "técnicamente correcto" pues el DRAE recoge tal acepción. Otra cosa es que tus interlocutores te entiendan, pues esta referencia no es tan común como otras como Abundio (otro famoso personaje de chistes) o [fulano/fulanito](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17999/5481).

Comment: Sobre "Abundio" pués por Colombia es completamente desconocido, mientras que los chistes de jaimitos si son muy comunes aunque nunca se usa como adjetivo. P.ej nunca diríamos "Pablo es un jaimito".

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus explicaciones adicionales !