# ¿Cuándo se añadió la entrada "zipizape" al diccionario?

Tags: etimología, españa, dle

En la pregunta reciente [¿Se puede llamar a un niño o niña “Jaimito (a)”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31114/5481) iba a incluir en mi respuesta otra referencia del DRAE a niños revoltoso con la entrada de *zipizape*.

Al ir a revisar la entrada para mi respuesta reparé en que la entrada dice que esta expresión es de origen onomatopéyico. Yo pensaba que se había añadido la entrada al diccionario porque los [populares personajes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipi_y_Zape) de Escobar (uno moreno (Zape) y otro rubio (Zipi), que se caracterizaban principalmente por las endiabladas travesuras) habían transcendido la cultura popular y sus nombres se habían convertido en sinónimo de "follón" o "travesura".

Viendo la entrada del diccionario, quizá la cosa fue al revés y Escobar eligió el nombre de los personajes en base a esta "onomatopeya". Escobar creó estos personajes en torno a 1946 (de acuerdo a [la entrada en wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipi_y_Zape#Evoluci%C3%B3n_de_los_personajes)).

¿Cuándo se añadió la entrada "zipizape" al diccionario? Me gustaría saber si fue antes o después de que este autor ideara a estos personajes, para ver si se puede descartar que la entrada fuese creada a partir de la popularidad de estos personajes.

Comment: Por cierto, la respuesta es 1780 (o sea, desde siempre). Aquí tienes la [columna de la página escaneada del diccionario de 1780](https://i.imgur.com/wwTqBqj.png). Sí, fue Escobar quien usó la expresión porque explicaba el argumento al lector solo con el título.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta que di en la pregunta enlazada para indicar que es mejor consultar el NTLLE, allí se puede ver que el _Autoridades_ recoge la palabra _zipizape_ ya en 1739.